# How to make Android Studio use existing .idea files?

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control

Following suggestions found on StackOverflow, my `.idea` folder is under version control, save for a couple of files (eg. `workspace.xml`). However, I opened my project with a new instance of Android Studio and instead of using the existing `.idea` files, Android Studio decided to... delete them. How can I make it reuse the existing ones?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have that trouble, I would restart Android studio and it would work. the second option would be to File > Invalidate and Restart.

The other options are Clean Project / Rebuild Project for Gradle. These are the options that helped me clear the issue.

Comment: Did not thing about invalidating... Thanks.